# Does Ghost Blog have any logs?

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm developing a theme locally for https://ghost.org/

I'm running into a ton of issues.

But there are no logs. I have no idea why it is failing.

Are there any options to display the logs while developing
a https://ghost.org/ on localhost?

Comment: have you seen this https://ghost.org/docs/concepts/config/#logging

Answer (score 7):

Yep, tho they are are pretty poor. Its in `content/logs`. It has helped me a bit with some filtering problems, at least it showed an error somewhere. There are a lot of unusable info there btw.